# print data of single linked list backward using stack

Tags: java

I am trying to print data of single linked list backward using stack but I am stuck.  The Stack class is as follows:

```
public class Stack{

    public boolean isEmpty(){};    
    public void push(int n){};    
    public int peek(){};
    public int pop(){};

}

public class node{
    int data;
    node next;  

}

public class list{    
    node first;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");

    for (String s: list){
        stack.push(s);
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
```